# Non-nullable instance field 'url' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: 1]

Non-nullable instance field 'articles' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.

Comment: make the URL late to make it non-nullable

Answer (score 3):

1. Stack overflow questions should include code, not screenshots (imo);
2. The IDE is literally giving you the tip you need. You're giving the `url` property a nullable value (and the same goes for other fields). Indeed `json['anything']` returns a `dynamic` value, which can be null. `dynamic` values are runtime error-prone, I'd advise against its use.

My best advice would be to do a full `Dart` [language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour), in which you'll understand [sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) a little better.